# echo specific row from array

Tags: php, database, arrays, row

I currently have a table like the one below.

```
ID  adPlacement     filePath    dateAdded   adName  adLink
12  1           Test 1.png  2013-02-12  Test 1  http://www.cuad.coop
13  1           Test 2.png  2013-02-12  Test 2  http://www.google.com
```

I am trying to randomly select a row and echo out the adName, adLink, and filePath all on separate echo statements.

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
$query_adSpot1 = "SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE adPlacement = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query_adSpot1, $server) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$row = array(
    'adName' => $row['adName'],
    'filePath' => $row['filePath'],
    'adLink' => $row['adLink']
);
$fileLocation = $row;
$fileLocations[] = $fileLocation;   
}
shuffle($fileLocation);
echo $fileLocation[0];
```

Right now when I run the script it will write test 2.png, or test 2, or http://www.google.com.

I want to be able to echo separately from a random row, but need the separate columns to equal same row.

```
echo filePath
echo adName
echo adLink
```

Comment: echo $filelocaton['indexname']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shuffling the wrong array, you should be using:

```
shuffle($fileLocations);
                     ^ This is the one with all your values
var_dump($fileLocations[0]);
// will show you an array with 3 elements from the same row in the database
```

What you are doing is re-ordering the last row found in your sql query.

Comment: How do I echo out the rows individually? I added this to the end:
shuffle($fileLocations);
var_dump($fileLocations[0]);
echo $row['adName'];

So if I want to echo out one of the elements.

Comment: @StevoBot Like `echo $fileLocations[0]['adName']`, `echo $fileLocations[0]['filePath']`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helped out and got it to do what I was looking for.

Comment: @StevoBot You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the check-mark below the vote-count) if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that. Just getting familiar with the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)function in `MySQL`

```
$query_adSpot1 = "SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE adPlacement = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query_adSpot1, $server) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['filePath'];
echo $row['adName'];
echo $row['adLink'];
```